# Google Aiy: no module named 'aiy.assistant.device_helpers'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, google-aiy

Iv been trying to get a python script to run which plays music from youtube.
if you say "play (song name)" it will go to youtube, find that song and play it. But every time I run it I get: No module named 'aiy.assistant.device_helpers'

The code was locate on [Github](https://gist.github.com/t1m0thyj/ddf6aaa6b3d37f602fedfd38c9af9d49).

The original forum is located on [Raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=114&t=182665)

Im running the Google Assistant library version 0.0.2

Comment: Did you install all the requirements for the Google Assistant SDK? Have a look at [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample).

Comment: @dsesto all my other Google aiy projects still work fine I don't even know if device_helpers exists